# Error handling forms which call sub procedures - MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

1. Yes, Access is used and it cannot be changed.
2. I have a form class object, let's say:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()

Dim Employee As String

    Employee = InputBox("Enter Name of Employee")
    
    If InStr(Employee, "Eka") > 0 Then
     Call Hello
    Else
     Call Hello2
    End If
    
End Sub
```

And I have one module. As you can see, I call each procedure from my form.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub Hello()
    
    MsgBox "Hello Eka"

End Sub

Public Sub Hello2()

    MsgBox "Hello stranger"

End Sub
```

The issue I have is with the error handling implementation as here we have the subsequent procedures which I call. I tried to add a simple `On Error GoTo` - see below to an individual sub-procedure to display a nice message and break the entire script execution but yes, the sub procedure will show a nice message, you click OK to close it and the main script just continues running. Can you, please, direct me to a source where I can read more on the potential solution or assist with it? I found something about global error handling, but not sure if it is relevant.

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
On Error GoTo errormessage

#TO-DO. VBA Code

Exit Sub

errormessage:
MsgBox "An error has occured. Please check your work."

End Sub
```

Comment: @Unandled, thank you for the adjustments, looks better. I hope I was clear with the issue.

Comment: I would suggest to read this https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Using_ErrRaise and this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94462/132083 Finally the aim of the game is to let the error bubble up the call stack by (re-)raising it and then handle it in the proper procedure.

Comment: Clear, thank you for the links. My understanding that even if I use err.raise in errormessage - see my code I would still have the same issue as in, the error appears, the sub-procedures breaks but then, the form code will continue running - let's assume apart from If I have more lines.

Comment: No, by (re-)raising the error to the calling function, there is no need to show a MsgBox in the sub procedure at all. The error handler of the calling function could do that if necessary, but it could also reraise the error to the next upper procedure and so on. And finally the procedure you mentioned with 'form code' could show the MsgBox and stop working in case.

Comment: Allow me to read on it, and I will respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small sample.

- `MainProcedure` calls `SubProcedure1` and this calls `SubProcedure2`.
- In `SubProcedure2` there will be a division by zero error.
- `SubProcedure2` handles this error and reraise it to the upper procedure in the call stack: `SubProcedure1`.
- `SubProcedure1` also handles it and also reraises it, now to `MainProcedure`.
- `MainProcedure` now shows the error. It can stop execution now if you want that.

Remark1: VBA unfortunately has no call stack information you could read at runtime. So in my example I always add the current procedurename as a new line to the top of the `source` property of the error.
So finally you can see where the error happened and how the call stack was.
But that is just an example.

Remark2: If you, for example, wouldn't place an active error handler in `SubProcedure1` the error would bubble up itself to `MainProcedure`, but then you couldn't add your call stack information.

```vb
Public Sub MainProcedure()
    On Error GoTo Catch

    SubProcedure1

Finally:
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "- MainProcedure" & vbNewLine & Err.Source, vbCritical
    Resume Finally
End Sub

Public Sub SubProcedure1()
    On Error GoTo Catch

    SubProcedure2

Finally:
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "- SubProcedure2" & vbNewLine & Err.Source, Err.Description
    Resume Finally
End Sub

Public Sub SubProcedure2()
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim value As Long
    value = 0

    Dim value2 As Long
    value2 = 1 / value

Finally:
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "- SubProcedure2" & vbNewLine & Err.Source, Err.Description
    Resume Finally
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, you provided with the keywords I was able to use to search for the solutions, thank you. What about On Error GoTo 0? Could it pass the error up? I will try your solution, thank you!

Comment: `On Error GoTo 0` would deactivate an active error handler in the procedure where you call it. So it would cause that errors, happening in this procedure, will be bubbled up the callstack to the next active error handler.

Comment: I did a quick test and it did threw an error. Can I, please, write again if tomorrow during in-depth testing I found sth?